# Why when adding to tool box in windows forms project a dll file there is no this little gear icon near it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In this screenshot on the left you see ExtdTextBox and ExtdTextBox1 and on both near it there is no this gear icon in purple. Where is it ?

[image: Tool Box Screenshot]

By purple gear i mean this for example:

[image: Purple Gear]

Comment: Maybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wk1wc0a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the standards ToolBox icon for `UserControls`.

This is probably what ExtdTextBox and ExtdTextBox1 are.

If you really wanted you could try to change the icon to show somthing else, at least if you have access to the sources and can add an `ToolboxBitmapAttribute` to it. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.toolboxbitmapattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wk1wc0a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for details.

However, even if you do that I don't think chosing a gear icon would be a good idea since these are usually picked for items that control settings. The example you show, from a more colorful incarnation of VS shows AJAX controls, which may explain the gear since they will talk to a server..

Also note, that the doc says that for the custom icon to show it is necessary to explicitly add the controls to the ToolBox via `Add to toolBox`..

I don't think it'll be worth the hassle.